# Can we use "IT" to refer to "WATER" in a case of dripping in the bathroom: "It is dripping from the ceiling?"

Tags: grammar, meaning, sentence-meaning, idiomatic-language, idioms-in-context

When you move to a house, you see there is water on the floor of the bathroom. And you see that it is coming from the ceiling. So, you call the handyman and he asks "what is the problem in your flat?". So, should I say:

**It is dripping from the ceiling to the bathroom.**

**The ceiling of the bathroom is dripping.**

I am not quite sure about both sentences, but in particular whether we can use **"IT"** instead of **"WATER"**, just like we can use **"IT"** instead of **"WEATHER"?**

So, which would be idiomatic?

Comment: Option 2 is not normal i would say “the bathroom ceiling is dripping”

Comment: @WendyG, what is the difference between "The bathroom ceiling" and "The ceiling of the bathroom"?

Comment: You should ***not*** understand "it" as specifically meaning "the weather" - it's a non-specific reference to "some aspect of the general situation". Hence ***It's hot** in the bathroom* refers to temperature, and ***It's a Long Way** to Tipperary* refers to distance. You can definitely say ***It's steamy** in the bathroom*, but I would understand ***It's dripping** in the bathroom* as meaning condensation in the steamy bathroom is running down the walls. I wouldn't expect the "dripping from the ceiling" sense *unless context had already established there was a leak somewhere **above.***

Comment: @yunus the word count mainly, I guess "the bathroom ceiling" is short for "the bathroom's ceiling" so the ceiling belonging to the bathroom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *can* use "it" without specifying beforehand what "it" is, but I wouldn't here, because it's less clear what you are talking about.

I think you should study two different uses of *it*:

1. *It* **as a pronoun referring to something else**, like "I saw a dog.  It was very big."  In this case, *it* doesn't make sense without specifying something else (*what* was very big?), and you could replace *it* with its referent, like "I saw a dog.  *The dog* was very big."
2. *It* **as a dummy subject**, because English grammar requires a sentence to have a subject, but sometimes there isn't an obvious one.  This is how "it" is used in the sentence "It is raining."  What is raining?  Nothing specific - so there is no word that you could use to replace *it* in the sentence.

In your example, "It is dripping", could we replace *it* with another word?  Yes, we could - we could say *water* is dripping from the ceiling.  Therefore this "it" is *not* a dummy, but a reference to something else, so it will not be entirely clear if you use "it" by itself.

Your example is a little ambiguous, because "dripping" is *could* be used as a general description of conditions, but as FumbleFingers says, it sounds like "The bathroom is generally humid and water is condensing everywhere", which is not what you mean.

---

On another note, the idiomatic way to phrase it would be "from the ceiling *of* the bathroom" or "from the bathroom ceiling", because the ceiling belongs to the bathroom, but "the ceiling *to* the bathroom" is not idiomatic to express ownership, and saying "from ___ to ___" sounds like it is talking about the direction that the water is dripping.

Answer (score 3):

No. As FumbleFingers says, that impersonal "it" suggests a weather phenomenon, which doesn't work here.

When I read that sentence, I find myself asking, "*What's* dripping?" and assuming it refers to something mentioned earlier in the conversation.

The most natural way I can think of to say this is:

> There's water dripping from the bathroom ceiling.

Comment: Agreed, Unless you have already specified the problem is water, I would include the word  as in your quote, to prevent any misunderstanding.